# Parameterize Integration Runtime in linked services of Azure data factory

Tags: devops, azure-data-factory

I have configured CI/CD pipelines for Azure Data Factory. I need to have a separate Integration Runtime for some linked services in Azure data factory for QA environment. When I deploy using the ARM templates of DEV Azure Data Factory from adf_publish branch, I am able to provide values for the parameter for only sql server name, key vault not IR. Is there any way I would be able to provide value of Integration Runtime in the linked service.
Thanks in advance

[Please click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdaoH.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by following the below link from Microsoft  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#use-custom-parameters-with-the-resource-manager-template

A new name can be added under the integration runtime arm template.

Answer (score 2):

Use connectVia property of linkedServices in the arm-template-paramerters-definition.json to change integration runtime from CI/CD

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices": {
        "*": {
            "properties": {
                "typeProperties": {
                    "baseUrl": "-::string"
                                  },
                "connectVia": {
                    "*": "="
                              }
                         }
             }
   }
```

Comment: This is a more straightforward answer than the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can go to the 'Manage' of your ADF instance and then go to 'Integration runtimes' to create a new Azure IR for your ADF.

[image]

You can create an azure IR based on azure or self hosted.

For more information, please have a look of these document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here, I have already created IR, but my problem is I have few linked services pointing to DEV IR. I need to change that to QA IRs through deployment. I can change it manually but need to get that automated. I am not able to find any variables to change IR. Is there any way?