# Parameterise IR name in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, etl

I need to pass IR names as a parameter in the ADF template during deployment. We have different names for production IR and IR's in lower environment. In order to do this we have changed to names of IR in the linked service by changing the parameter configuration file in ADF. But we cant change IR defined in the pipeline when using dataflows.
For eg:

```
{
        "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/pipeline_name')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "properties": {
            "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "dataflow_name",
                    "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "policy": {
                        "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                        "retry": 0,
                        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                        "secureOutput": false,
                        "secureInput": false
                    },
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "dataflow": {
                            "referenceName": "dataflow_name",
                            "type": "DataFlowReference",
                            "parameters": {
                            },
                            "datasetParameters": {
                            }
                        },
                        "staging": {},
                        "integrationRuntime": {
                            "referenceName": "IR_NAME",
                            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
                        },
                        "traceLevel": "Fine"
                    }
                }               
            ],
            "policy": {
                "elapsedTimeMetric": {},
                "cancelAfter": {}
            },
            "parameters": {
            },
            "annotations": [],
            "lastPublishTime": "2022-11-16T10:27:40Z"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/dataflows/dataflow_name')]",
            "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/integrationRuntimes/', IR_NAME)]"
        ]
    }
```

Here i want the referenceName under integrationRuntime to be parameterised. I tried the following setup with the parameter configuration file in ADF

```
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
    "*":{
        "properties":{
            "*":{
                "properties":{
                    "typeProperties":{
                        "integrationRuntime":{
                            "referenceName":"="
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not seem to be working. Any input on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Parameterise IR name in ADF

AFAIK, there is no such option available to parameterize Integration runtime in ADF see this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40699). You have to select it manually.

> If you try to set the parameterize Integration runtime value you might face issue like this.
> [image]

**Here I tried to parameterize it, but we have to mention specific Integration runtime name.**

The current workaround is to duplicate everything like LinkedServices, Datasets change them accordingly and use it in your pipeline.

You can raise the feature request for Integration runtime parameterization [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)

Comment: There is a way to do this, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665505/parameterize-integration-runtime-in-linked-services-of-azure-data-factory . I did this and it works during deployment. But when you have a pipeline which has a dataflow in it then we have to specify IR in the pipeline directly. I need to parameterise it as well. I followed the same method as i did for linked service but its not working.

Comment: There is also a microsoft page about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters